# Less modifyVars not overriding the styles in webpack when using AntDesign

Tags: css, webpack, less, antd

Although I can see the style visible in the element styles, the reverse of the intended behaviour is happening, it is actually being over ridden by the original style.

This is my current webpack.config.dev.js configuration for the style over ride:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// common function to get style loaders
const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
  const loaders = [
    require.resolve('style-loader'),
    {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: cssOptions,
    },
    {
      // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
      // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
      // package.json
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: {
        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
        // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
          require('postcss-preset-env')({
            autoprefixer: {
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            },
            stage: 3,
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
  if (preProcessor) {
    loaders.push(require.resolve(preProcessor));
  }
  return loaders;
};

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/343
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  entry: [
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs,
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  optimization: {
    // Automatically split vendor and commons
    // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969633336732905474
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false,
    },
    // Keep the runtime chunk seperated to enable long term caching
    // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969679223278505985
    runtimeChunk: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
      .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
      .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
    alias: {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
      // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
      PnpWebpackPlugin,
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    plugins: [
      // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
      // from the current package.
      PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'style-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'less-loader',
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
                  javascriptEnabled: true,
                  modifyVars: {
                    '@primary-color': '#0eccd0', // `#0eccd0 ~'!important'`
                     '@link-color': '#0eccd0', // `#0eccd0 ~'!important'`
                     '@border-radius-base': '20px',
                     '@font-size-base': '20px',
                  },
              },
              }]
          },
          // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
          // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
          // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
           // {
           //   test: /\.less$/,
           //   loader: 'style!css!postcss!less?{modifyVars:{"@primary-color":"#1DA57A"}}'
           // },
           // {
           //    test: /\.less$/,
           //    include: [/src/],
           //    use: [
           //      require.resolve('style-loader'),
           //      {
           //        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
           //        options: {
           //          importLoaders: 1,
           //          modules: true
           //        },
           //      }
           //    ],
           //  },
           // {
           //   test: /\.less$/,
           //   use: [
           //     require.resolve('style-loader'),
           //     {
           //       loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
           //       options: {
           //         importLoaders: 1
           //       },
           //     },
           //     {
           //       loader: require.resolve('less-loader'), // compiles Less to CSS
           //       options: {
           //         javascriptEnabled: true,
           //         modifyVars: {
           //           'primary-color': 'rgb(14, 204, 208)',
           //           'link-color': 'rgb(14, 204, 208)',
           //           'border-radius-base': '2px',
           //         }
           //       }
           //     }
           //   ],
           // },
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // Process application JS with Babel.
          // The preset includes JSX, Flow, and some ESnext features.
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              customize: require.resolve(
                'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
              ),
              plugins: [
                ['import', { libraryName: "antd", libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true }],
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                  {
                    loaderMap: {
                      svg: {
                        ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // Don't waste time on Gzipping the cache
              cacheCompression: false,
            },
          },
          // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
          // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
            exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              configFile: false,
              compact: false,
              presets: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                  { helpers: true },
                ],
              ],
              plugins: [
                ['import', { libraryName: "antd", libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true }]
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // Don't waste time on Gzipping the cache
              cacheCompression: false,

              // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
              // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
              // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
              // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
              sourceMaps: false,
            },
          },
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
          // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
          // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
          // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
          {
            test: cssRegex,
            exclude: cssModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
            }),
          },
          // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
          // using the extension .module.css
          {
            test: cssModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            }),
          },
          // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
          // Chains the sass-loader with the css-loader and the style-loader
          // to immediately apply all styles to the DOM.
          // By default we support SASS Modules with the
          // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
          {
            test: sassRegex,
            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({ importLoaders: 2 }, 'sass-loader'),
          },
          // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
          // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
          {
            test: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders(
              {
                importLoaders: 2,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              },
              'sass-loader'
            ),
          },
          {
            test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
          }, {
            test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
          }, {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
          }, {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: "file-loader"
          }, {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
          // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/, /\.(less|config|variables|overrides)$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    // Environmental variables activated
    new Dotenv(),
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
    // the requesting resource.
    new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
    // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
    // having to parse `index.html`.
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
      publicPath: publicPath,
    }),
    // TypeScript type checking
    useTypeScript &&
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
        typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
          basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
        }),
        async: false,
        checkSyntacticErrors: true,
        tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
        compilerOptions: {
          module: 'esnext',
          moduleResolution: 'node',
          resolveJsonModule: true,
          isolatedModules: true,
          noEmit: true,
          jsx: 'preserve',
        },
        reportFiles: [
          '**',
          '!**/*.json',
          '!**/__tests__/**',
          '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
          '!src/setupProxy.js',
          '!src/setupTests.*',
        ],
        watch: paths.appSrc,
        silent: true,
        formatter: typescriptFormatter,
      }),
  ].filter(Boolean),

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
  // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
  performance: false,
};
```

The project was set up with create-react-app and was ejected so as to have more control over the project itself.

As you can see from the following picture, the style is loaded, however it is being over ridden.
[image: over ridden modifyVars less]

I have tried many different variations of this, including editing the package.json file and other approaches, yet have been unsuccessful. I have also tried a number of other methods listed on the https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme site, however not been successful so far.

Any suggestions would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is a lot of unnaccery code in your webpack.config.dev.js  try to reopen and eject the project and folow the process of antd again.

what seems to be the problem is that the styles of ant design imported later again. so I would recommend to uninstall and install again the antd library.

Also I think the problem is in that lines

```
        ['import', { libraryName: "antd", libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true }],
```

it occurs twice after your theme config. try to delete it.

Im using antd with my theme and i didn't import these plugins.

my config that works:

```
{
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              modifyVars: require('../config/antTheme'),
              javascriptEnabled: true,
            },
```

config/antTheme.js

```
module.exports = {
  'primary-color': '#7839d5',
  'link-color': '#4a90e2',
  'font-family': '"futura-pt", sans-serif',
  'line-height-base': 1.3,
};
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works as it was a while back now... may very well. So thank you U.Rush. I will put how we solved it below.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:
The way Ant Design says to work with styles when you use Create React App:
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app
Add antd/dist/antd.css at the top of src/App.css.

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Solution:
So when you want to override variables, you have to remove import of ~antd/dist/antd.css as it overrides your modifyVars override.

This was further discussed here: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14272#issuecomment-453359894